# How to total number of users in JIRA Cloud REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

When we try to get all users in JIRA REST API, we get response with maxResult of 50. But the thing is that how can I know how many total users are there in total? We do not get that in either response or in header, so how to know the total?

Answer (score 0):

It's returning maxResult of 50 because it is the default behaviour of the Get All Users REST API.
Have you tried passing the maxResult as a query parameter like:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/users?maxResult=100' \
  --user 'email@example.com:<api_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

As mentioned in the REST API [doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-users/#api-rest-api-2-users-get)

Comment: Thanks Sumit, Yes I have tried, as we go on increasing the value of maxResults, it give that much results, like for 50 it returns 50, for 100 it returns 100 and so on. This is good. But how can I know where the end lies? I can not guess at random that how any total users are there.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't (depth=all) feature as such for the JIRA API response.

Comment: Okay, Thanks Sumit